# Can I upload a spreadsheet to MediaWiki

Tags: excel, file-upload, mediawiki, twiki

I'm attempting to port some content from TWiki to MediaWiki and whereas the former seems to allow the uploading of spreadsheets, the latter does not. I'm not interested in displaying / previewing the spreadsheet - just a hyperlink would do fine.

I appreciate that I could store the Excel files 'off-wiki' and externally link to them, but it would be good to keep it all together if at all possible - otherwise we'll have to think about maintaining seperate but logically linked filesystems etc.

Also, I would like to keep it in its original form rather than converting to HTML / JPG etc.

Has anyone hit this problem and if so, how was it solved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in **LocalSettings.php**. You can then add this line: **$wgFileExtensions = array('png', 'gif', 'jpg', 'jpeg', 'svg', 'xls');** (or whichever extensions you want). But be aware that you might want to switch this off after you've done your transfer otherwise your server will quickly become full with files!

See also [Manual:$wgFileExtensions](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3a%24wgFileExtensions)